# com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: {0} java.lang.NullPointerEx

Tags: web-applications, websphere

While trying to deploy the springboot project in IBM Webshere 9, we are receiving this error:

> EDT] 000000a9 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp
> notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while
> destroying context: {0}
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextDestroyed(WeldInitialListener.java:134)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.managedobject.ManagedObjectListenerWrapper.contextDestroyed(ManagedObjectListenerWrapper.java:138)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed(WebApp.java:1867)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.destroy(WebApp.java:3288)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.destroy(WebAppImpl.java:1561)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:97)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
> at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImp

The same project is deployed in Tomcat and it is working fine.Please guide us in terms of any dependency need to add or any configuration we need to do.

We're trying to deploy the springboot application in IBM Webshere 9.0.12.

Comment: Please check log earlier in the stack as `Exception caught while destroying context` suggest that it is thrown when the app is being stopped not started.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?